# Gatsby app build fails due to actioncable using window object

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby, actioncable

My *Gatsby* app uses *react-actioncable-provider* package to connect with *rails* server. *React-actioncable-provider* uses *actioncable* package which is using `window` object. The app is working fine in development mode, but during build it fails due to the mentioned `window` object being undefined. So I have Wrapper component:

```
const cable = ActionCable.createConsumer(HEROKU_CABLE)
...
<ActionCableProvider cable={cable}>
    <App></App>
</ActionCableProvider>
```

And App component:

```
render(){
...
<ActionCableConsumer 
   channel={{ 
              channel: 'GameSessionChannel', 
              id: this.state.game_session }} 
               onReceived={this.handleReceived}>
 </ActionCableConsumer>
...}
```

I tried moving  `cable = ActionCable.createConsumer(HEROKU_CABLE)` to `componentDidMount(){}` as `var`, and changing Wrapper component this way:

```
if ({(typeof window !== 'undefined')&& ActionCableProvider})

   {<ActionCableProvider cable={cable}>
       <App />
     </ActionCableProvider> }
else
    { <App /> }
```

but now comes another error:
`WebpackError: Invariant Violation: Minified React error #130`

in

> universalModuleDefinition:10 ba
>
> lib/webpack/universalModuleDefinition:10:2

Edit:

I forgot to mention one important fact:
Following Gatsby official documentation I added below code to `gatsby-node.js`. It seems like the last error is caused by that module not being loaded if I understand it correctly.

```
    exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /actioncable/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

How could I bypass it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It was only an experiment so i ended up not using ActionCable. Hope you had more luck.

Comment: I'm actually bypassing this whole problem now with Hasura - so elegant!  No more graphql gem or ActionCable!